# C# Bit to Bit XOR & File I/O

Tags: c#, io, bit-manipulation, xor

OK, I have a 35 MB file, that is Encrypted with Bit to Bit XOR(Bitwise XOR I believe) and I'd like to know a good way to decrypt it, and then encrypt it again, using File I/O on C#.

Here is the Enc/Dec algorithm:

```
Encrypt:----------------------Decrypt:
Bit  0 -> Bit 26--------------Bit  0 -> Bit 18
Bit  1 -> Bit 31--------------Bit  1 -> Bit 29
Bit  2 -> Bit 17--------------Bit  2 -> Bit  7
Bit  3 -> Bit 10--------------Bit  3 -> Bit 25
Bit  4 -> Bit 30--------------Bit  4 -> Bit 15
Bit  5 -> Bit 16--------------Bit  5 -> Bit 31
Bit  6 -> Bit 24--------------Bit  6 -> Bit 22
Bit  7 -> Bit  2--------------Bit  7 -> Bit 27
Bit  8 -> Bit 29--------------Bit  8 -> Bit  9
Bit  9 -> Bit  8--------------Bit  9 -> Bit 26
Bit 10 -> Bit 20--------------Bit 10 -> Bit  3
Bit 11 -> Bit 15--------------Bit 11 -> Bit 13
Bit 12 -> Bit 28--------------Bit 12 -> Bit 19
Bit 13 -> Bit 11--------------Bit 13 -> Bit 14
Bit 14 -> Bit 13--------------Bit 14 -> Bit 20
Bit 15 -> Bit  4--------------Bit 15 -> Bit 11
Bit 16 -> Bit 19--------------Bit 16 -> Bit  5
Bit 17 -> Bit 23--------------Bit 17 -> Bit  2
Bit 18 -> Bit  0--------------Bit 18 -> Bit 23
Bit 19 -> Bit 12--------------Bit 19 -> Bit 16
Bit 20 -> Bit 14--------------Bit 20 -> Bit 10
Bit 21 -> Bit 27--------------Bit 21 -> Bit 24
Bit 22 -> Bit  6--------------Bit 22 -> Bit 28
Bit 23 -> Bit 18--------------Bit 23 -> Bit 17
Bit 24 -> Bit 21--------------Bit 24 -> Bit  6
Bit 25 -> Bit  3--------------Bit 25 -> Bit 30
Bit 26 -> Bit  9--------------Bit 26 -> Bit  0
Bit 27 -> Bit  7--------------Bit 27 -> Bit 21
Bit 28 -> Bit 22--------------Bit 28 -> Bit 12
Bit 29 -> Bit  1--------------Bit 29 -> Bit  8
Bit 30 -> Bit 25--------------Bit 30 -> Bit  4
Bit 31 -> Bit  5--------------Bit 31 -> Bit  1
```

Comment: Quote from above:
"I'd like to know a good way to decrypt it, and then encrypt it again, using File I/O on C#"

Comment: That doesn't look like a xor 'encryption', just a bit shuffle.  Use FileStream and BitVector32.

Comment: I thought it was Bitwise XOR. I guess I was wrong, so what procedures should I take to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a bitwise XOR - it's effectively a bitwise [substitution cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher). You realise it's only "encryption" in the loosest sense of the word, right?

Basically you'll need two steps:

- Write methods to transpose bits for encryption/decryption, each one taking a 32-bit integer and returning a 32-bit integer
- Read the file one 32-bit integer at a time, apply the appropriate operation and write out the result to the other file. You may well want to use `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` for this.

(Obviously you can optimize with buffering, but that's the general gist.)

You may find it's easiest to work with `uint` instead of `int` to avoid worrying about sign bits. Something like this:

```
public static uint Encrypt(uint input)
{
    return (((input >> 0) & 1) << 26) |
           (((input >> 1) & 1) << 31) |
           (((input >> 2) & 1) << 17) |
           ...
           (((input >> 31) & 1) << 5);
}
```

You could make this table-driven with a table for encryption and a table for decryption, but I'm not sure I'd bother.

Note that if you're *actually* using this to store sensitive information, you should start using **real** encryption as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to do a function to get a single bit and a function to save it wherever you want:

```
int getBit(int position, int word)
{
    return ((word >> position) & 1);
}

void setBit(int position, int value, ref word)
{
    word = (word & (value << position));
}
```

Then you have to do each conversion manually, something like (if I understood your algorithm correctly):

```
int b1 = getBit(0, word);
int b2 = getBit(18, word);
setBit(0, b1 ^ b2, ref word);
```

Answer (score 1):

That isn't [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). If it was you'd simply XOR the data with the same value again to [decrypt it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher).

What you are describing is some kind of bit scrambling encryption.

As others have said, this is not secure encryption. It uses a method commonly known as "[security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)."